# PHP + mySQL : Storing and displaying prices and percentages

Tags: php, mysql, decimal

I'm creating a website in which I work a lot with prices and percentages.

I'm storing all prices on mySQL as Decimal(10,2).

The thing is if I enter 1000,25 it stores 1000... What am I doing wrong? Maybe I didn't understand correctly how decimal(10,2) works... Thanks on beforehand guys!

Comment: use a dot instead of a comma

Comment: in Decimal type you are entering comma (10000,25). That is why you are getting error

Comment: we will need your exact php and mysql code to find your error. But I guess gbestard is right and you will need to use a dot instead of a comma.

Comment: if you insert value 1000,25 it MUST give you error..!!! As the type is Decimal(10,2).

Comment: Thanks guys, I get mixed up on how we use the coma and the dot on comparison to other countries... I'll just enter a default sample value for users on the form :)

Answer (score 1):

you have to enter 1000.25 not 1000,25

Comment: if you insert value 1000,25 it MUST give you error..!!! As the type is Decimal(10,2)